# JavaScript - invalid argument IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I've got a little JavaScript problem. The code is working in Opera and Firefox browser but not in Internet Explorer 8. Does anybody know why?

```
function createbtn(object, inner) {
    var hover = document.createElement("div");
    hover.setAttribute("class", "myarea");
    if (inner) {
        hover.style.width = object.width - 16 + "px";
        hover.style.height = object.height - 16 + "px";
        hover.style.top = getposy(object) + "px";
        hover.style.left = getposx(object) + "px";
    } else {
        hover.style.width = object.width + "px";
        hover.style.height = object.height + "px";
        hover.style.top = getposy(object) - 8 + "px";
        hover.style.left = getposx(object) - 8 + "px";
    }
}
```

I'm just learning Javascript. Any feedback welcome.
Simon

Comment: what is `getposx` and `getposy`?

Comment: can you put ur full code in a http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: If you use the developer tools (F12), you can check what rendering mode IE 8 is in. Can you post what it is? I'm suspecting it's in Quirks Mode.

Comment: @Simon You should cache the `hover.style` object inside a variable (both to reduce redundancy and boost performance)...

Comment: Check the return of you getposx, getposy, they probably are not returning a number

Comment: @Šime Vidas Sounds interesting. Can you please explain a little further? I'ld love to boost the performance!

Comment: @Simon You get a slight performance improvement (around 15%, a bit more in IE). See here: http://jsperf.com/caching-the-style-object Retrieving the style object of a given DOM element once instead of multiple times obviously takes less time...

Comment: @Simon Note that you should follow my suggestion foremost to get rid of the redundancy. This makes your code more readable, and easier to maintain. The performance aspect of this improvement is a minor part.

Answer (score 9):

If `object.width` is less than 16

```
hover.style.width = object.width - 16 + "px";
```

then this will produce a string with a negative sign at the front, which is illegal since widths have to be non-negative.

You can fix this by saying

```
hover.style.width = Math.max(object.width - 16, 0) + "px";
```

and similarly for height.

Many browsers ignore invalid content, but IE in certain modes is stricter, so you are probably just getting silent failure in the others.

Comment: I'm using IE8 browser mode **standard**. I fixed the negative width/height problem but the position setting isn't working. The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/AT825/ What is wrong with it? Thanks to all the great feedback till now.

Comment: Are you sure that `getposy` and `getposx` are not returning NaN?

Comment: I'm not sure. For `hover.style.top = getposy(object) + "px ` "; the IE8 debugger tells just an _Invalid Argument_

Comment: @Simon, and what is the argument?  To what does the expression `getposy(object) + "px"` evaluate in the debugger?

Comment: It's returning NaN. What I need to archive is to get the position of the image. This is what I've so far: http://jsfiddle.net/AT825/ How to make it work in IE8 ?

Comment: You need to fix your `getposx` and `getposy` to not return NaN.  Probably somewhere in those you are calling `parseFloat("")`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it has to do with `hover.setAttribute("class", "myarea");`. If IE 8 is running in IE 7 or lower Mode this won't work. Then you have to use `hover.className = 'myarea'` (supported by all browsers).

> The sAttrName parameter requires the name of the desired content attribute and not the
>   Document Object Model (DOM) attribute. For example, in IE8 mode, this method no longer requires sAttrName to be "className" when setting, getting, or removing a CLASS attribute. Earlier versions of Internet Explorer and Internet Explorer 8 in compatibility mode still require sAttrName to specify the corresponding DOM property name.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Check the mode IE is running.